# Can syntax parameters be used to replace syntax?

Tags: syntax, macros, racket

I'm trying to use syntax parameters in order to inject new syntax where I need it to be injected. The result of this is then used in other syntax.
However, it's not working as I expect it to. Here's a minimal working example:

```
(require racket/stxparam)
(require (for-syntax racket/stxparam))

;; declare parameter to be replaced with code
(define-syntax-parameter placeholder
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error
     (syntax-e stx)
     "can only be used inside declare-many-commands")))

;; this is just to print what 'arg' looks like
(define-syntax (print-syntax stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ arg)
     #'(displayln 'arg)]))

;; this is the top-level entity invoked to produce many commands
(define-syntax-rule (declare-many-commands cmds)
  (begin
    (let ([X 10])
      (syntax-parameterize
       ([placeholder (make-rename-transformer #'X)])
       cmds))
    (let ([X 20])
      (syntax-parameterize
       ([placeholder (make-rename-transformer #'X)])
       cmds))))

(declare-many-commands
 (print-syntax placeholder))
```

What I would like to get as result when running this is:

```
10
20
```

but what I get is:

```
placeholder
placeholder
```

**EDIT:**

Posted a new question to refine the problem: [Injecting syntax at compile time using Racket's syntax parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50047354/426092)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `print-syntax` macro quotes its input, and inputs to macro transformers are unexpanded syntax. This means that the expansion of `(print-syntax placeholder)` will always be `(displayln 'placeholder)`, and no macroexpansion ever occurs under `quote`, so the `placeholder` binding in scope is irrelevant.

If you want to use the syntax parameter, you need to actually produce a reference to the `placeholder` binding. In this case, you just need to remove the use of `quote`. You could change `print-syntax` to `(displayln arg)`, but at that point, there’s really no reason for `print-syntax` to be a macro, since it’s equivalent to the `displayln` function. Just use that instead:

```
(declare-many-commands
 (displayln placeholder))
```

This will print `10` and `20` as you expect.

It’s possible you really do want the `quote`, and I don’t understand your question. In that case, though, I think it’s difficult for me to understand what you’re getting at without some additional context.

Comment: It was apparently a bad example that I gave in the question. I've now updated it using code from the actual application to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: @gablin A few things. First of all, it is considered bad form to significantly rewrite your question in a way that invalidates existing answers, even if your initial question wasn’t the one you wanted to ask. Just ask a new question. Second, your code seems wildly overcomplicated, since you’re using a lot of very low-level operations instead of high-level things like `syntax/parse`. Third, I don’t think I can answer your question without an understanding of what `define-instruction` itself does, so can you please include a real implementation instead of a dummy one? Then I’d be willing to try.

Comment: Alright, I've rolled back the question to its original state and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50047354/426092